# Why qbittorrent shuts down lightdm?

Tags: login, shutdown

Immediately after I run qbittorrent application it opens up and right after it's loaded I'm suddenly at login screen. Tried reinstalling, uninstalling installing but didn't help...

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ubuntu and qbittorrent are you running ?

Here is a link for the latest stable release of qbittorrent if that helps any:

https://launchpad.net/~hydr0g3n/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise